NTP client on Compact-RIO RT linux system
I'm trying to synchronize the time of my National Instruments real time system (model Crio 9053) running a Linux OS. I tried a ntpdate 192.168.10.3 command and this working well, but after that the time difference with the NTP server begins to increase continuously. I've tried another hardware (same model) but in this case, within a few seconds, the offset continues to grow, until it reaches 2.796 seconds. Take a look!

Why? This really disturbs me!
This is the packages installed in the Crio:


Welcome to the site. Please don't post screenshots of console output. They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Are the pictures important? What do they say?

Do you have a time service daemon (ntpd, chronyd) already running? Running ntpdate on top of those can have this effect

The 'set-the-time-and-disappear' is the desired behaviour of ntpdate. It's just a one-shot tool to set the RTC, rather than a daemon that keeps the clock in synch.
You need a daemon running on your system, to regularly update the RTC. One reasonably small-footprint, widely available implementation is chrony, but it wouldn't surprise me if NI have their own stuff. Search for ntpd.
Installing the service can be done in plenty of different ways, depending on the flavour of Linux you're running. Does this 'NI Linux OS' run on anything like systemd? Or maybe OpenRC?

You might also be interested in hwclock, which can be used to set the HW RTC from the system clock and vice-versa.

You seem to have another problem as well, though. Your clock drifts way too rapidly. NTP can cope with slight clock drifts, normally on the order of seconds per hour. If the clock is off by a factor of two, it's not something that NTP can handle.

You're right, but wrong at the same time: A clock that's off by a factor of roughly two, no NTP client daemon will be able to continously adjust that. It's outside the range of what the offset frequencies in Linux can do, and too much to do it somewhat precisely in userland software. So, this constitutes a hardware defect. Probably something that went amiss when building that operating system image, might be easy to fix (some kernel config is wrong about an internal clock, maybe). Definitely escalate this as a support case with NI.

Ooops. Yes indeed. I missed that it was that wrong.
Yes, it definitely sounds like a configuration mixup in the OS image.

I'm still upvoting your answer, because to  someone with lesser problems it applies. Mind mentioning that "your err's too high, but if it weren't…" in the answer?

You seem to have a hardware or hardware configuration problem: your offsets are too large to be reliably corrected by software that checks a reference clock via NTP.
So, I'm afraid there's not much the software community here might do for you: someone needs to either fix the hardware, or the assumption about how fast some clock runs in the configuration of your OS – and it's probably going to be your hardware vendor.
